# How to delete next row from csv if first value repeats

Tags: python, pandas

My file.csv is below

```
id,state,country
44,1,WD,India
5,WD,India
44,AL,Japan
390,AL,Japan
17,AL,Japan
17,SA,BEL
```

need to delete second row first comma separate value repeats here `44,17` repeats

Expected out

```
id,state,country
44,WD,India
5,WD,India
390,AL,Japan
17,AL,Japan
```

- Any method is fine python, bash shell

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates('id')`.

Comment: `awk -F, '!seen[$1]++' file.csv` for the file structure you have posted.

Comment: @Jetchisel what the meaning of `!seen[$1]++`

Comment: Remove second and subsequent instances of each input line, without having to sort them first. `seen` is just a variable name, and `$1` is the first field `++` means increment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to delete any row that has the same value in the first column with any other rows

you would use a for loop to loop through all the values and you could detect if any was a duplicate using a list

```
File = open(X.csv, r)
Data = File.readlines()
File.close()
List = []
for line in Data:
    line = line.split(",")
    if line[0] in List:
        print("This row isn't gonna be written to file")
    else:
        List.append(line)

File = open(X.csv, w)
for Y in List:
    File.write(List[Y][0] + "," + List[Y][1] + "," # and so on
File.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to a dataframe and then save it back:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id'], inplace=True)
df.to_csv('test.csv')
```